# (Lua) Why is my producer-consumer Lua coroutines experiment not yielding the expected resault?

Tags: lua, coroutine

I have created the following two coroutines a producer and a consumer in an attempt to learn/understand the coroutines.

```
function count01to10()
  for i = 1, 10 do
    coroutine.yield(i) 
  end
end

function printNumber(number)
  while number ~= nil do
    print("Counter: ", number)
    coroutine.yield()
  end  
end


function main()
  local number = 0

  print("Creating coroutines")
  local counter = coroutine.create(count01to10)
  local printer = coroutine.create(printNumber)

  print("Executing coroutines")
  while (10 > number) do
    isSuccessuful, number = coroutine.resume(counter)
    print("counter: ", coroutine.status(counter))
    coroutine.resume(printer, number)
    print("printer: ", coroutine.status(printer))
  end

  print("Finished")
end

main()
```

The output is:

```
Creating coroutines
Executing coroutines
counter:    suspended
Counter:    1
printer:    suspended
counter:    suspended
Counter:    1
printer:    suspended
...
Counter:    1
printer:    suspended
Finished
```

I am expecting the ouput to print out the numbers 1 to 10. Why is this not happening and is that a proper way to use coroutines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coroutine resumes at the same point where it yield (or just after it), not at the beginning.

Your code for `printNumber` does not change `number`, so the output you get is not surprising.

To fix this, use `number=coroutine.yield()` in `printNumber`.

The arguments passed to `resume` are returned by `yield`.

Comment: So the first time printNumber is executed it gets the 1 as an argument but for any consequent calls it needs to get the value (2 to 10) passed to resume and returned by yield (and not as an argument)?